# Keep jar running on server after ssh disconnect

Tags: jetty, java

How can I keep a jar, that I started via ssh, running on a server after disconnect my ssh?

Comment: SSH needs a way to leave the connection a little bit open, rather than closing it completely when you disconnect.  I suggest `ssh --ajar`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `GNU screen` or `tmux`. This is one important feature of those programs.

Other than that, refer to `man nohup`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `nohup` when executing and then use the `disown` command.

Consider adding more details to your questions. You didn't even tell us what operating system you're on.